# Lightning:TreeGrid size limitations and alternatives to asynchronously fetch parent data

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightningtreegrid

Other than the limitations given in [lightning:treeGrid](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:treeGrid/specification), what are the limitations on the number of parent rows that can be displayed in the tree grid? Definitely we cannot more than 50000 records that does or doesn't have a  child due to SOQL query limits in a first go. Unlike [lightning:datatable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable/documentation) which has **loadMoreOffset** functionality to fetch the data based on infinite scrolling. I know we can fetch nested items asynchronously in the treegrid as well but is there a way we can asynchronously fetch parent as well ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no inherent (read: hard-coded) limits built in to any of the iterator components. You're free to try to load as much as you want into them. The 50,000 row limit can easily be bypassed using client-side chunking of the data. I demonstrate this in my [key prefix scanner](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/219323/2984) app I wrote. Unfortunately, it's still in VF (I'll be updating this soon). The premise is largely the same, though: query records in ascending order by ID, and for each subsequent call, provide the last known ID from the earlier query result and have Apex filter it that way. Do any extra sorting client-side. Note that while I said there's no inherent limits, you'll find that devices with less memory, CPU, etc will struggle to load very large tables. You might want to implement faux scrolling and your own virtual grid design instead of the SLDS versions. Lightning *is* fast, but DOM rendering is always the largest bottleneck, so if you can somehow minimize that, you'll be better off.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Its definitely a lot to process for me. Looks like to get past the hard apex limits we can leverage client side chunking but better off building our own tree grid for flexibilty and performance, Is that correct ?

Comment: @codeyinthecloud Yes, using the out-of-the-box component is fine for up to a few thousand elements, but you'll get really bad performance if you try to render all 100k+ records in a single tree. I ran a test in the playground, up to 1000 rows was reasonably okay, but the performance took a long time after that. I would say that it's probably impossible to render more than a few thousand rows in a tree, grid, or table without some advanced management. Consider pagination if you want to use the out-of-the-box components.

Comment: @codeyinthecloud In fact, here's a toy for you to play with. Put in a number, watch the performance drop away as you scale up. [Playground Link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/skU5p15qY/1/edit)

Comment: Sure. Let me playaround with that. I did see the grid was unresponsive when I loaded 2000 rows with treegrid.